# How do I perform a filter function on data from an Axios API call in React?

Tags: reactjs, filter

I am having trouble displaying my yogaCard in the return statement. When I call it as `{yogaCard}` I get a message saying it is undefined.

```js
  if (yogas.length > 0) {

                let yogaCard = yogas.filter((yoga) => {
                        if (searchPose === "") {
                            return yoga
                        }
                        else if (
                            yoga.english_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPose.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
                                return yoga
                            }
                    }).map((yoga) => (
                   <div key={yoga.id} style={{width: '20%' }} className="card"  
                    >
                    <img className='yogaphoto' src={yoga.img_url}/>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h2>{yoga.english_name}</h2>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                    ))
            }
 return (
            <>           
<div className="yoga"> 
    <div className='yogasearch'>
           <h1>Yoga Poses</h1> 
           <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search by pose" onChange={event => {setSearchPose(event.target.value)}}/>

    </div>

        <div className="row">
             {yogaCard}
        </div>

    
</div>

            </>
        )    

    }
        
    
    export default IndexYogas
```

Comment: Can you format your code, so it is actually readable? No one is going to have a look at this if it is not formatted properly.

Comment: Also this is not the whole component, please show us more and tell what you have tried so far.

Comment: pls, write with state and js file in different segments. Then it would be readable and understandable to anyone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing how you're retrieving your `yogas` data from axios or any way to debug your current issue, but I'd recommend passing your data retrieved from axios to a child component that contains all those div boxes and formatting, etc.

```
function MainPage() {
    const [yogas, setYogas] = React.useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        // axios call to populate data
        requestYogaInfo().then((resp) => {
            setYogas(resp.data); // this depends on the shape of your webservice response
        });
    }, []);


return (
        <>           
        <div className="yoga"> 
             <div className='yogasearch'>
               <h1>Yoga Poses</h1> 
               <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search by pose" onChange={event => {setSearchPose(event.target.value)}}/>
             </div>
             <div className="row">
                 {yogas && yogas.length > 0
                     ? (
                     yogas.filter((yoga) => {
                        if (searchPose === "") {
                            return yoga
                        }
                        else if (
                     yoga.english_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPose.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
                                return yoga
                            }
                    }).map((yoga) => (
                   <div key={yoga.id} style={{width: '20%' }} className="card"  
                    >
                    <img className='yogaphoto' src={yoga.img_url}/>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h2>{yoga.english_name}</h2>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                    ))
                     )
                     : null
                 }
             </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )  
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, please provide a working code sandbox so that any issues can be properly debugged.